# Can wake on lan funciton work by the device itself

Tags: wake-on-lan

There's a device with WOL function and it's enabled in Linux.
In order to test the functionality of WOL

1. I can wake it up by another computer (`wakeonlan -i device_ip device_mac`)

   where can I find the log or message about WOL success after this sent command
2. if I do the command on the device itself when its power state is ON, can I get any successful message?